# How to add batch namesapce in eclipse

Tags: spring-batch

How to add spring-Batch namespace in eclipse. I found the fallowing name spaces.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"`enter code here`
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">


</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [official doc - Domain batch namespace](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/domain.html#domainBatchNamespace)